# Регулярные выражения для парсинга пары значений разделённых двоеточием

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, парсер

Пытаюсь распарсить URL с помощью регулярных выражений.

Допустим есть такой URL:

```
https:/test.ru/news/detail/int:id/
```

Необходимо с помощью регулярного выражения найти параметры, которые могут быть динамическими, они отличаются наличием двоеточия и записаны в формате:

```
<тип данных>:<название переменной>`
```

В примере выше динамический параметр, это `int:id`.

Для поиска таких параметров пытаюсь использовать такую регулярку. Она должна возвращать `int:id` и ничего больше:

```
r'(int|float|str|bool):[a-zA-Z_]+'
```

Но она возвращает мне какую-то дичь:

```
import re

regexp = r'(int|float|str|bool):[a-zA-Z_]+'
path = 'https:/test.ru/news/detail/int:id/'

print(re.search(regexp, path).groups())
# ('int',)
```

Так же пробовал:

```
regexp = r'((int|float|str|bool):[a-zA-Z_]+)'
print(re.search(regexp, path).groups())
# ('int:id', 'int')

regexp = r'((int|float|str|bool):([a-zA-Z_]+))'
print(re.search(regexp, path).groups())
# ('int:id', 'int', 'id')

regexp = r'((int|float|str|bool)(:[a-zA-Z_]+))'
print(re.search(regexp, path).groups())
# ('int:id', 'int', ':id')

regexp = r'((int|float|str|bool)(:)([a-zA-Z_]+))'
print(re.search(regexp, path).groups())
# ('int:id', 'int', ':', 'id')
```

И тысячи других вариаций скобок, которые тоже не работают.

Я не понимаю, почему они возвращают вообще что-то без двоеточия, если в регулярке чётко указано, что выражение должно содержать двоеточие и 1 или более символов после него. Пробовал тоже самое в JS, он при таких же регулярках другие результаты возвращает (но тоже дичь какую-то).

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: а что вы хотите получить в результате?

Comment: @MaxU я же написал - `int:id` и ничего больше

Comment: `print(re.search(regexp, path).groups(0))` так?

Comment: @timur это костыль какой-то, который ещё и не всегда будет работать, вот вздумается ему вернуть `int` на первом месте

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`groups()` возвращает найденные группы. Группа - содержимое простых круглых скобок `(...)`. В вашей регулярке

```
(int|float|str|bool):[a-zA-Z_]+
```

это будет `int` или `float` или т.д., но не `:[a-zA-Z_]+`, ведь эти символы не в скобках.

Здесь

```
((int|float|str|bool):([a-zA-Z_]+))
```

уже 3 группы: первая общая скобка, т.е. всё выражение, далее опять `int` или `float` или т.д. и далее `[a-zA-Z_]+`.

Чтобы не захватывать группу, надо написать её так:

```
(?:...)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
pat = r'((?:int|float|str|bool):[a-zA-Z_]+)'

m = re.search(pat, path)

res = m.group(1) if m else None
```

---

результат:

```
In [60]: print(res)
int:id
```

---

**UPD:**  пояснение:

`(?: ...)` - non-capturing group, т.е. группа, которая не захватывается/сохраняется. Это удобно использовать когда надо найти одно из нескольких возможных значений и когда нам не нужно сохранять найденный паттерн

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется будет проще использовать не регулярки, а просто str.split:

```py
s = 'https:/test.ru/news/detail/int:id/'
print(s.split('/')[-2])
```

Если же вы хотите именно с помощью регулярки, то вы должны получить не все группы, а только первую, содержащую всю строку:

```py
regexp = r'(?:int|float|str|bool):[a-zA-Z_]+'
print(re.search(regexp, path).groups(0)) #=> int:id
```

Comment: а если `int:id` окажется в середине? ;)

Comment: @MaxU автор про такое ничего не сказал. Если же оно всё-таки может быть по середине, то тогда использовать регулярку